# Angular - Can´t set values to variable

Tags: angular

The error is simple. I get latitude and longitude from browser and  prints the correct value, then i need to pass this variable to the view so i put the value  in a variable. I print the variable and return null.

I use Angular 8.

The code

```
  long: number;
  lat: number;    
  constructor() {}
      ngOnInit() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
          this.lat = location.coords.latitude;
          console.log(this.lat); //RETURN NULL
          this.long = location.coords.longitude;
        });
```

So anybody see what´s wrong in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a normal `function` as a callback for `getCurrentPosition`, therefore the context for `this` not the class instance. You need to use an arrow-function:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(location => {
  this.lat = location.coords.latitude;
  console.log(this.lat); //RETURN NULL
  this.long = location.coords.longitude;
})
```